# How to allow only one edit at time using Angular js inline editing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, inline-editing

Hello I am using Angular js and creating one application with table inline editing using this [`demo jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MVDotNet/fw5y9n23/).

Here if you see you can edit multiple row at a time but I just want to allow one row edit at a time.

How I can stop the user to edit other row if any one row is already in edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep one Scope variable isBeingEdited. Set it to true in editAppKey and false in saveField. In editAppKey only do operation if isBeingEdited is false

Comment: no if you can see there is a direct set false and true to the scope editMode from the button before I do anything it automatically set it to true I can't change anything.

Comment: editMode is from the parentScope ... by assigning editmode="true" I'm not sure that you are assigning the value to the parent scope, maybe you create a new property.  So it could be better to use editmode with in the right scope...

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, can you give me a favor. Can you please update my jsfiddle for this to edit at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Add One more property called CanEdit to your $scope.appkeys to false,And make it true when you try to click any Edit Button.rest all CanEdit property should be false.disable the button according to CanEdit property.You can do this by checkbox 
When you click edit.Checkbox(CanEdit)will true.

Comment: Can you show me in the jsfiddle I think it will not work still.

Comment: Please update my fiddle sir so I can see how I can do that!

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OJXEANCPMOmPR7VJY4Us?p=preview either you can hide or disable the button.its upto you

Comment: Ohhh ok thanks I will update my code hope it works in my end.